# Apple Iwork Numbers: How to conditionally highlight a cell

Tags: macos, iwork-numbers

I am using apple numbers to do some modeling.

(For those of you who are not familiar it is the apple version of excel that makes awesome looking charts, but has a bit less functionality).

I am using Numbers 08 version 1.

I have three cells right now with this:

```
-------------------------------------
| A1 | A2 | =IF(A1>A2, "PROBLEM!","")
-------------------------------------
```

However I would prefer to somehow highlight A1 in red when it is higher than A2.  Is there anyway that I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a workaround using a novel idea to overlay tables:

http://www.numberstemplates.com/2007/10/05/conditional-formatting-hack/

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know, there is no way to use cell references in the conditional formatting dialog box in numbers 08.

i use numbers 09 and there you are able to do exactly what you want.

still, it can't hold a candle to excel.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why?